# Forcing do_save after Rails fixture load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, fixtures, before-save

AFAICT before_save (and probably other callbacks) isn't called when the Rails fixture loads. Is there any way to cause before_save to be called?

Comment: This is Rails 3.1. It happens whether unit testing or using rake db:fixtures:load, so I don't think that's relevant.